# Site admin cant see items added

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have list in my site, user have site admin access, he can add items but cant see them he added. Only users with site collection admin can see list items.

I have verified list permissions, it inherits access from site (site admin have full access to site). For testing removed inheritance and given full access to  user but it still didn't work. I have also verified version settings, view settings, advanced permissions - everything looks fine.

Comment: try to verify the permissions of both users on the list. ( Use the check permission function )

Comment: You could try creating a new list for testing purposes.  Repeat the steps you describe in your question - do you see the same behaviour?  If it behaves differently, then you have isolated the problem to some settings on your list.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not set any filters on the view:
Navigate to the list->modify view->choose Show all items in this view:
[image]